# Sampling from conditional distribution to impute NaN values in joint

Tags: python, sampling

Suppose that X and Z are sets of non-overlapping dimensions where `$P(X,Z)$` is the joint distribution over all features. I have two sets of data:

1. X and Z are observed, and
2. only X is observed.

Given the first set, I would like to MLE fit a multivariate Gaussian. Then using X, observed in the second set, sample values for Z using the conditional distribution `P(Z|X)`

Note: I am not trying to frame as a multivariable regression problem. Rather I want to impute missing Z values in the second set given the first. And I believe that sampling from the conditional gaussian is sufficient for my purposes.

Is such functionality possible in numpy, scipy, etc. (extended Python ecosystem)?

Comment: To get from a joint Gaussian distribution to a conditional over a subset of dimensions, see e.g. Chapter VIII of the book by Richard von Mises titled something like "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics". No doubt the relevant formulas are in many other places as well. FWIW I recommend just going full Bayesian instead of simple imputation; multiple imputation is better than simple imputation, and just doing the integrals (i.e. the Bayesian approach) is better still.

Comment: Would this be better on https://datascience.stackexchange.com?